# Error in decompose(ts(x[1L:wind], start = start(x), frequency = f), seasonal) : in R

Tags: r, time-series, lapply, holtwinters, forecast

I can't understand why i get the error mentioned in post title.

so what i do.

data example

```
mydat=structure(list(date = structure(c(3L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("apr-15", 
"feb-15", "jan-15", "jul15", "jun-15", "march-15", "may-15"), class = "factor"), 
    x1 = c(653411L, 620453L, 742567L, 578548L, 720100L, 553740L, 
    588145L), x2 = c(242108L, 210841L, 255046L, 185243L, 257159L, 
    182594L, 246051L), x3 = c(234394L, 289563L, 341791L, 293608L, 
    306807L, 285190L, 279252L), x4 = c(309228L, 226175L, 292387L, 
    183745L, 223322L, 161218L, 201499L)), .Names = c("date", 
"x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

mydat<- read.csv("path.csv", sep=";",dec=",")

mydat <- stats::ts(mydat[,-1], frequency = 12, start = c(2015,1))

library("forecast")

    my_forecast <- function(x){
      model <- HoltWinters(x,beta = FALSE, seasonal = "additive")
      fcast <- forecast(model, 5) # 5 month
      return(fcast)
    }

progn=lapply(mydat[1:34], my_forecast)
```

and the error

```
 Error in decompose(ts(x[1L:wind], start = start(x), frequency = f), seasonal) : 
  time series has no or less than 2 periods 
5.
stop("time series has no or less than 2 periods") 
4.
decompose(ts(x[1L:wind], start = start(x), frequency = f), seasonal) 
3.
HoltWinters(x, beta = FALSE, seasonal = "additive") 
2.
FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
1.
lapply(d2[1:34], my_forecast)
```

How to fix it?
The main idea it is perform HoltWinters analysis for all 34 variable.

Comment: I suggest you just read the raw data without declaring the structure. And then, use store it as ts(mydat, start=c(2015,1), end=c(2015,7), frequency=7)

Comment: @RendyEzaPutra, i get same error Error in decompose(ts(x[1L:wind], start = start(x), frequency = f), seasonal) : 
  time series has no or less than 2 periods

Comment: can you run my code and follow the error. In what step it occures

Comment: okay, the problem is the lapply function. lapply returns a list of the same length as X, each element of which is the result of applying FUN to the corresponding element of X. You can just run your 'my_forecast' function. my_forecast(ts(mydat, start=c(2015,1), end=c(2015,7), frequency=7))

Answer (score 1):

the problem is the lapply function. lapply returns a list of the same length as X, each element of which is the result of applying FUN to the corresponding element of X. You can just run your 'my_forecast' function.

```
mydat=structure(list(date = structure(c(3L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("apr-15", 
    "feb-15", "jan-15", "jul15", "jun-15", "march-15", "may-15"), class = "factor"), 
        x1 = c(653411L, 620453L, 742567L, 578548L, 720100L, 553740L, 
        588145L), x2 = c(242108L, 210841L, 255046L, 185243L, 257159L, 
        182594L, 246051L), x3 = c(234394L, 289563L, 341791L, 293608L, 
        306807L, 285190L, 279252L), x4 = c(309228L, 226175L, 292387L, 
        183745L, 223322L, 161218L, 201499L)), .Names = c("date", 
    "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -7L))

mydat<- read.csv("path.csv", sep=";",dec=",")

mydat <- stats::ts(mydat[,-1], frequency = 12, start = c(2015,1))

library("forecast")

my_forecast <- function(x){
   model <- HoltWinters(x,beta = FALSE, seasonal = "additive")
   fcast <- forecast(model, 5) # 5 month
   return(fcast)
}

my_forecast(ts(mydat, start=c(2015,1), end=c(2015,7), frequency=7))
```

Comment: provide please output.

Comment: your data is x1 : x4 though. in this case, I assume the data is a univariate time series. And I dont have the full data, because it seems you loaded path.csv, and I didnt

Comment: i don't know how  upload dataset on stackoverflow, but original dataset i upload here  https://dropmefiles.com/8OMTJ (path.csv) size 10kb